# When I import images as planes it shows a random line at the top

Tags: import, image

So I am making plants for a game and sometimes when I use Import Images as Planes, it has this random line at the top. I've done numerous test to see if my images were the problem, but every time I reimport the file it still has the line. I tried creating a new image, getting rid of other layers, erasing the background numerous times and it still has it. There are some images though that do not have this problem, but it seems to occur most of the time. If anyone could help, that would be more than wonderful.

[image]

The top has the random line in it.

[image]

The line is not in this image.

Comment: Suggest posting / linking original images.  Can then at least see if same behaviour occurs... oh and welcome to bse.

Comment: Set ithe image texture to Clip rather than Repeat - looks like this is simply bleeding from the bottom of the image as it wraps to the next repeat. Similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45725/29586

Comment: @RichSedman can I suggest you make your comment an answer? This problem is affecting multiple users (the one you link, also this one from 2015 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39238/height-map-boundary-problem/87394#87394) that use "Import as a plane". They might come across this question via search engines and benefit from your tip.

Answer (score 5):

Image textures employ interpolation to blend pixels into the neighbouring space so as to smooth the image rather than provide a hard pixelated effect. With the image set to Repeat there is actually a copy of the image just beyond the image borders. In your case the image against the opposite edge is butter right up against the edge and so the interpolation is causing it to 'bleed' across te border - the bottom of your grass image is bleeding into the top.

To resolve this, simply set the image to *Clip* rather than *Repeat*.

The option is located under the "Texture" panel:

- If you're using Cycles

  [image]
- If you're using Blender render

  [image]

Comment: Glad to help. If this resolves the problem, please 'Accept' the answer (click the 'tick' button alongside the answer). This will make it easier to find for others experiencing the same issue (and you'll also gain some reputation points yourself).